# Conflict between org and yas: \Cc &

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet

In org mode, `\Cc &` goes back to the reference to a link; but this binding is suppressed by yasnippet.  Do I have to redefine it, or can I prevent yasnippet from creating these bindings in the first place?